# Interpreting a Python function from JSON data

Tags: python, json, sympy

I am trying to determine the equivalence of two simple functions passed to python via json like so:

PHP:

```
$data = array("2*x", "x*2");
$result = shell_exec('python /path/check.py ' . escapeshellarg(json_encode($data)));
```

Python:

```
import sys, json
from sympy import *

try:
    data = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
except:
    sys.exit(1)

x = Symbol('x')

response = data[0]
answer = data[1]

result = response==answer

print json.dumps(result)
```

My assumption is that result returns false because the response and answer are being interpreted as strings. How can I compare these two functions as if I set the variables in python like so:

```
response = 2*x
answer = x*2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the strings into SymPy expressions:

```py
sympify(answer) == sympify(response)
```