# Parsing AsciiMath to Python expression

Tags: php, python, sympy, mathjax, asciimath

I am attempting to pass 2 functions to a python script via JSON in order to evaluate their equivalence. The issue I am having is that the input is in [AsciiMath](http://asciimath.org/) notation. It seems `sympify` has no issue parsing the expressions from the strings if the format is consistent with that of Python expressions. Is there a way to parse AsciiMath notation into something Python can interpret? I have been unable to find any libraries that offer such a feature.

PHP:

```
$data = array("2*x", "x*2"); // returns true as expected
$data = array("2x", "x2"); // AsciiMath notation does not work
$result = shell_exec('python /path/check.py ' . escapeshellarg(json_encode($data)));
```

Python:

```
import sys, json
from sympy import *

# Load the json data sent from PHP
try:
    data = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
except:
    sys.exit(1)

x = Symbol('x')

# Convert string inputs to expressions
user_response = sympify(data[0])
correct_answer = sympify(data[1])

# Perform equivalence comparison
result = user_response == correct_answer

# Return result
print json.dumps(result)
```

Comment: What the heck is "ASCII math notation"?

Comment: @ user2357112 Please see: http://asciimath.org/

Comment: Here's a python library that parses AsciiMath: https://github.com/favalex/python-asciimathml I found it with Google, what did you try?

Comment: That's AsciiMath, not "ASCII math notation" or "ASCII notation".

Comment: @user2357112 understood. I have corrected the language. thanks

Comment: @Barmar - can python evaluate mathML expressions?

Comment: MathML is a markup language, not something intended to be evaluated.

Comment: @Barmar - right, so how does that library help?

Comment: This is some sort of sequal to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55931761/interpreting-a-python-function-from-json-data

Comment: Here's something about converting MathML to Sympy: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/6070 I can't tell whether there's something usable in there.

Comment: @hpaulj yes it is

Comment: Someplace in its intro `sympy` explains that '2x' is not valid Python, as a result not valid `sympy` either.  That doesn't mean that `sympify` (or some variant) couldn't translate that.  `**` versus `^` is another Python quirk.

Comment: When you talk about Python interpreting an expression, are you asking about the core Python interpreter, or the `sympy` package?  `2*x` means different things depending on what `x` is.  It could be a number, a string, a list, or a `sympy.Symbol`, or a `numpy.ndarray` - or anything else that defines the relevant operator.

Comment: @hpaulj - I am asking about sympy or any other library that could parse the expression to something python could interpret

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When asking a question like this, you should demonstrate the problem.  Here's what I think is happening.

With one set of expressions, `sympify` works fine:

```
In [144]: sympify('2*x')==sympify('x*2')                                             
Out[144]: True
```

But with the other pair:

```
In [145]: sympify('2x')==sympify('x2')                                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SyntaxError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sympy/core/sympify.py in sympify(a, locals, convert_xor, strict, rational, evaluate)
    367         a = a.replace('\n', '')
--> 368         expr = parse_expr(a, local_dict=locals, transformations=transformations, evaluate=evaluate)
    369     except (TokenError, SyntaxError) as exc:
 ...
SympifyError: Sympify of expression 'could not parse '2x'' failed, because of exception being raised:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

That's just for the '2x' string.  For the other string:

```
In [146]: sympify('x2')                                                              
Out[146]: x₂
```

`sympify` is expecting strings that could evaluated in a `sympy` environment

> Converts an arbitrary expression to a type that can be used inside SymPy.

It says `arbitrary`, but the docs are somewhat more restrictive, as described.

```
It currently accepts as arguments:
   - any object defined in sympy
   - standard numeric python types: int, long, float, Decimal
   - strings (like "0.09" or "2e-19")
   - booleans, including ``None`` (will leave ``None`` unchanged)
   - lists, sets or tuples containing any of the above
```

In the context of the question that means expressions using `x` which was defined with

```
x = Symbol('x')
```

but ones using `y` would have problems.

===

`sympify` produces a `sympy` expression:

```
In [161]: expr = sympify('2*x')                                                      

In [162]: type(expr)                                                                 
Out[162]: sympy.core.mul.Mul
```

which can then be 'evaluated' in various ways.  I could describe this a 'modified', except `sympy` stresses that the expression is immutable.  These actions all produce new expressions or values:

```
In [163]: expr.subs(x,21)                                                            
Out[163]: 42

In [164]: expr.diff(x)                                                               
Out[164]: 2

In [165]: expr.integrate(x)                                                          
Out[165]: 
 2
x
```

===

Also such an expression cannot be evaluated by the core Python interpreter,

Define a new symbol, and expression:

```
In [166]: y = Symbol('y')                                                            
In [167]: expr = sympify('2*y')                                                      

In [168]: expr                                                                       
Out[168]: 2⋅y
```

Reassigning `y` to be a Python integer, does not change the value of `expr`:

```
In [169]: y = 21                                                                         
In [170]: expr                                                                       
Out[170]: 2⋅y
```

but it does allow us to evaluate a regular Python expression:

```
In [171]: 2*y                                                                        
Out[171]: 42
```

But the same Python expression using `x` symbol produces a `sympy` expression:

```
In [172]: 2*x                                                                        
Out[172]: 2⋅x
```

===

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html

This `parsing` module has means of handling expressions like '2x'.  At least the docs show:

(again in a `isympy` session):

```
In [173]: from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr                          

In [174]: from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr, standard_transformations
     ...: , implicit_multiplication_application                                      

In [175]: transformations=(standard_transformations + (implicit_multiplication_applic
     ...: ation,))                                                                   

In [176]: parse_expr('2x', transformations=transformations)                          
Out[176]: 2⋅x

In [177]: parse_expr('x2', transformations=transformations)                          
Out[177]: 2⋅x
```

So it does handle your example, but I don't know enough of `asciimatch` to know how much else works.

That page also talks about a `LaTeX` parser, https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html#experimental-latex-parsing

Comment: thank you for the help. and you are correct - the examples above are exactly the issue

Comment: how would approach the issue from here? I have been researching for a few days and have had little luck devising a strategy to move forward

Comment: thank you so much for the thorough response. you have provided excellent context and examples. I think there is enough here for me to move forward and experiment with different inputs.